# Like button, display likes only

Tags: facebook-like

Is it possible to display the page likes only with the "Like button"? I know it is a sum of different types, but the only thing i want to know, and display to my visitor, are the likes.

Is there an easy way to disable the total count and only show the like count?

Greetings,
Jacob

Comment: Do you want to hide the like button and just show the like count?

Answer (score 0):

just set the "button" on display:none or use the facebook API